# Mapbox GL JS - Is there a way to specify a different zoom level for mobile devices?

Tags: mapbox, zoom, mapbox-gl-js, mobile

With Mapbox GL JS, is there a way to specify a different zoom level for mobile devices? I found two examples, both from the older mapbox.js (links below), but I can't seem to translate them to GL JS and get them to work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087638/how-can-i-resize-my-map-according-to-the-device-width/24091293
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910594/leaflet-responsive-design-creating-different-zoom-levels-for-different-screen

For reference, this is the issue that I'm having. On desktop, the zoom level shows the appropriate features:

[image]

But then on mobile, it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to try to get it to show at smaller zoom level when loaded on mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out just after posting but figured I'd leave it up in case other people run into this in the future.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 420px)" );

if (mq.matches){
    map.setZoom(14.34); //set map zoom level for desktop size
} else {
    map.setZoom(11); //set map zoom level for mobile size
};
```

Comment: You could also get Mapbox GL JS to fit the bounds of a feature of interest, which would work for every possible screen size and orientation. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/